# Query to select latest record when using Group By - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

There is a table structure:

```
ID1 (int), ID2 (int), AddedAt (datetime)
```

where **ID1** and **ID2** are primary keys. Now This table contains already up to **300,000** records and I need to restructure the table to have **1-1** relationship. Meaning i need to drop the **ID1** from being primary key and make only ID2 to be the primary key but there are records that already contain multiple **ID2s** for each **ID1**.

Now before i do that I need to have a query to select all the records where multiple **ID2** exists and remove them, only need to leave one record ID2 and that record has to be latest one which is determined by **AddedAt datetime** column.

This is what i have so far:

```
 SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS Total
 FROM TestTable
 GROUP BY ID2
 HAVING Total > 1
```

this successfully returns all records but **AddedBy** does not come out to be the latest one. What do i need to add to this query to get the latest record only 1 for Grouped By ID2 so that i can make the ID2 to be the primary key.

If this cant be done in MySQL can it be done in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

> this successfully returns all records but AddedBy does not come out to be the latest one.

Most SQL dialects **forbid** selecting column values that are not part of the GROUPing – MySQL allows it (depending on server settings), but delivers a value from a *random* row for these columns.

What you want are [the Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).